# Как изменить с помощью медиа запросов ссылку на картинку?

Tags: html, css

Предположим, что у нас есть обычный header:

Html:

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <span class="home">Home</span>
      <a class="first_nav_link" href="#">work</a>
      <a class="first_nav_link" href="#">faq</a>
    </div>
    <a class="second_nav_link" href="#">log in</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #111111;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 15px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.home {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.first_nav_link {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;

}

.second_nav_link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Как для определенной ссылки изменить ее текст на изображение или иконку?То есть, при экране с максимальной шириной 480 пикселей нужно поменять текст в ссылке на иконку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот так, попробуйте поиграть с шириной окна вашего браузера, чтобы увидеть как работает пример:

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #111111;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 15px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.home {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.first_nav_link {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

.second_nav_link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .home,
  .first_nav_link,
  .second_nav_link {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    vertical-align: center;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .home:before,
  .first_nav_link:before,
  .second_nav_link:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  .home:before {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXyN4.png);
  }
  .first_nav_link:nth-of-type(1):before {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oempp.png);
  }
  .first_nav_link:nth-of-type(2):before {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7q5j.png);
  }
  .second_nav_link:before {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwZ7Q.png);
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <span class="home">Home</span>
      <a class="first_nav_link" href="#">work</a>
      <a class="first_nav_link" href="#">faq</a>
    </div>
    <a class="second_nav_link" href="#">log in</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
a::before {
  content: "It's a link";
}

@media all and (max-width: 580px) {
  a::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2037/2037710.svg);
    background-size: contain;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
```